# Deleting modified recurring Outlook appointment occurrence causes MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND error

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

So I'm manipulating Outlook appointments using Redemption and I found that if I try to delete a recurring appointment occurrence that has already been previously edited, then the delete method throws a COM exception saying MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND.

This is how I can reproduce this:

1. Obtain the master `RDOAppointmentItem` for the pattern first.
2. Get one of the occurrence: `rdoMasterAppointment.GetRecurrencePattern().GetOccurence(1)`
3. Make a change and save the occurrence: `rdoAppointmentOccurrence.Subject = "Changed"; rdoAppointmentOccurrence.Save();`
4. Let the process finish, then come back, and get the same occurrence, then try `rdoAppointmentOccurrence.Delete()`

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please send an email to the support contact at http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/contact.htm and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I ran into this situation because I was looking into "restoring" an edited occurrence back to it's original state (before it's been edited). Although so far I don't think both Redemption and the Interop library expose a way to do this.